# Formio UI not displaying correctly with ReactDOM

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom, formio

I'm new to react and I'm learning to use hooks, but I can't seem to get the Formio plugin to work correctly with a component.

I'm not sure how React.DOM would be implemented with hooks, but Formio's [docs](https://github.com/formio/react-formio) state:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {FormBuilder} from 'react-formio';

ReactDOM.render(
  <FormBuilder form={{display: 'form'}} onChange={(schema) => console.log(schema)} />
  , document.getElementById('builder')
);
```

I tried implementing on a component, but ReactDOM kept giving me an error. This code works, but the plugin is all wonky so I know something isn't working correctly.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import  ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
import { FormBuilder } from 'react-formio';


const FormBuilderPage = props => {

    return (
        
            <FormBuilder 
               form={{ display: 'form' }}
               onChange={(schema) => console.log(schema)}
            />
            //,document.getElementById('builder')
                    
        )
        
   // This returns an error     
   return (
        
        ReactDOM.render(
            <FormBuilder form={{display: 'form'}} onChange={(schema)                => console.log(schema)} />
            , document.getElementById('builder')
          )
                    
    )
   
}

export default FormBuilderPage;
```

When I add ReactDOM.render I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.
```

Any advise would help!

Comment: Could you show use the errors you're getting ? Importing does not work in SO snippets

Comment: @Treycos updated. I added the snippet of code to show what causes the error. I know it's a novice mistake.

Comment: `document.getElementById('builder')` just in case, this actually returns something?:)

Comment: What's your HTML? Is an element with `id="builder"` present?

Comment: @CameronLittle You're right, it doesn't exist. I changed it to an ID that does and it populates. The same issue is happening now with styling, but I'm guessing it's a conflict between their css and mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So their documentation wasn't very clear, but React.DOM is not needed. There was just a css import that I had to add to the index.html file.

So this works!

```js
import React from "react";
import { FormBuilder } from 'react-formio';


const FormBuilderPage = props => {

    return (
        
            <FormBuilder 
               form={{ display: 'form' }}
               onChange={(schema) => console.log(schema)}
            />
                    
        ) 
}

export default FormBuilderPage;
```

```html
<!-- Formio CSS-->
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://unpkg.com/formiojs@latest/dist/formio.full.min.css"
    />
```